# mongodb client to array or object to use?

Tags: mongodb

its been awhile since I used the mongodb client. In the past I thought I would do something like this

```
let result = await mondodbConnection.findOne(query, options).toArray()
```

and then access the result using dot notation

```
result.id
```

but it says toArray() is not a function and I cannot find information on this. Can someone point me in the right direction, thanks

Comment: `findOne` will result in object, no need of `.toArray()`.

Comment: `findOne` returns only **one** document, thus `toArray()` is pointless.